# Do you have to tell the truth?

Tags: hanabi

If you wanted somebody to discard a card, it seems advantageous to lie and say it's something that is obviously not playable. Do you have to tell the truth about the card you are giving a clue about?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you must always tell the truth about cards in Hanabi. When you give information you give it about the card. If you give color you must give it for all cards of that color. If you give it about the number you must give it about all cards with that number. Given those two facts it is absolutely against the rules to lie.

Here is a link to the rules.

https://www.villagehome.org/blog/attachment/index.php/4923/1/regle_en_hanabi.pdf